# Incomplete list pop in list comprehention

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I have been trying to `pop` elements in list comprehention using `takewhile` function and I came into things that is for me hard to understand. My terminal session looks like this:

[image]

However when i tried the same thing with strings then problem didn't occur:

[image]

Can someone explain to me that happened in the first scenario? Why `g.pop(0)` has returned only `[1, 2]`?

Transcript for copying (why Stack doesn't have collapsible sections ):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
from itertools import takewhile
>>> g = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [a for a in takewhile(lambda x: x < 4, g)]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [g.pop() for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x < 4, g)]
[5, 4, 3]
>>> g = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [g.pop(0) for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x < 4, g)]
[1, 2]

>>> g = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> [a for a in takewhile(lambda x: x != '4', g)]
['1', '2', '3']
>>> [g.pop() for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x != '4', g)]
['5', '4', '3']
>>> g = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> [g.pop(0) for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x != '4', g)]
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, because i've tried to use `deque` which raised `RuntimeError: deque mutated during iteration`.

Execution goes like this:

1. `g[0] = 1 < 4; g.pop(0) => 1`
2. `g[1] = 3 < 4; g.pop(0) => 2`
3. `g[2] = 5 > 4; break`

This also explains why it worked in 2nd case, because during iteration `'4'` hasn't been hit.